# Windows Server 2008 R2 and Keyboards

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, usb, keyboard

I have a machine with WIN server 2008 R2 installed, when the machine boots up, it says keyboard failure.

The keyboard I had was from an older machine and was PS/2, I got a PS/2 to USB converter in order for it to work, but it says keyboard failure and doesn't work.

Is it because it's pretty old and that's it, or does it have to be USB?  I'm going to look into a new one, but want to make sure I don't get this issue again...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably nothing to do with Windows. The error you referenced sounds like it comes from the BIOS. My guess is your keyboard or adapter is broken. Could also be the PS2 port on the mobo.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyboard failure is from the BIOS which sounds to be the case I agree with Will.  On top of that it could also be a bad or broken adapter or perhaps not properly seated.  Check that the pins on your PS2 keyboard are not bent or broken as this is also a strong possibility.

To rule things out try using the keyboard on another computer with a PS2 port directly.  If it works you'll know the keyboard is fine.  If it does not work then you know the keyboard was the problem.

If the above doesn't help you figure it out then it is likely to just be a bad adapter or not seated properly (some of these adapters are very stiff at first and are hard to make proper contact in my experience).